# How to make a .bat file and merge logs

Tags: batch-file, logging, merge, cmd

Thank you for your helps in this web.
I must make a .bat file,to merge many logfiles in the same folder with log's filename.

I made the cmd program.

```
for %1 in (*.log) do echo [%1] >> all.txt & type %1 >> all.txt
```

I can go to the goal in the cmd,but .bat cannnot.

please help me!

** folder tree is

```
a folder a1.log
         a2.log
         a3.log...

b foledr b1.log
         b2.log
         b3.log...
```

so,i want merge

```
a1,a2,a3.log⇒a_all.txt
b1,b2,b3.log⇒b_all.txt
```

it is not problem that merged file name is same all.txt.
because i want check the two files with the winmerge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - the for variable percent signs need to be doubled in a batch file.

```
@echo off
for %%a in (*.log) do echo [%%a] >> all.txt & type "%%a" >> all.txt
pause
```